# Is there a way to solve for when some function returns an integer?

Tags: integers, mathematica

I currently have a function (single variable) that is under a square root, and I want to find when the value of the function returns an integer value, in terms of the variable.

Like if I took f(x) = SQRT(x+1) , I want it to return as like x = C^2 + 2C. I see that its like completing the square except the function under the square root, but is slightly too complicated to do by hand. I was trying to use Mathematica, but I don't think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: $x=f^2-1$ so $x=c^2-1$ in your notation, I guess. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Sort of, but the function I am working with is a 4th power polynomial, not sure how that changes the situation

Comment: so you want the solutions of a diophantine equation of fourth degree. I dont have the knowledge to help you with this but at least you know now what are you looking for, so you can search information about it.

Comment: There is very little we can say in general. However, if you told us what your specific function is, maybe someone here is clever enough to figure it out.